# What is wrong with the syntax of this sqlite code?

Tags: sql, sqlite

My SQLite SQL code looks like this;

```
INSERT OR IGNORE INTO box_infos (symbol, name) 
VALUES( 'DXSS.SI', 'DXSS Group') 

UPDATE box_infos 
SET name = 'DXSS Group' 
WHERE symbol = 'DXSS.SI';
```

However, I get

> Syntax error near "UPDATE"

What is wrong with the code? I used the answer below as a guide.
https://code.i-harness.com/en/q/377728

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"Chained" SQLite commands each need to be terminated by ';'. In this case, SQLite does not know where the `INSERT` ends and the `UPDATE` begins. All things being equal, this should work, as long as the `INSERT` query is terminated with `;`.

Comment: Is this ; termination a requirement only for SQLite? Do SQL statements for MySQL have the same requirement?

Comment: Oh gosh it's been a long time. Probably, as indicated [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-preferences-general-editors.html) (See _Non-Standard SQL Delimiter:_).